# How do I install the Rich Document patch on solr on Windows?

Tags: tomcat, solr, lucene

The documentation says to look at this page: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToContribute#Working_With_Patches

But it hasn't been very helpful.

I've downloaded rich.patch (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRichDocuments#Updating_a_Solr_Index_with_Rich_Documents_such_as_PDF_and_MS_Office) and I've cd'd into my solr home directory. I tried to run the following command:

```
patch -p0 -i rich.patch
```

And it just asks me which file I want to patch. For example, it would say this:

```
can't find file to patch at input line 2681
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:

Index: example/solr/conf/solrconfig.xml
```

When it prompted me, then, for the file I wanted to patch, I just typed in the path to my solrconfig.xml file, "C:\xampp\solr\conf\solrconfig.xml"

When I do this, it successfully updates my java/org folder to contain ExcelParse.java, PowerPointParser.java, etc. But when I try to post a word document using "java -jar post.jar *.*", I get the error

```
FATAL: Solr returned an error #400 Bad Request
```

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rich.patch has been fixed with Solr 1.4 version and you should be able to parse and index Rich documents with Solr out of the box without any patches.

As Mauricio mentioned check out [ExtractingRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler)

Also check out : -

[posting-rich-documents-to-apache-solr-using-solrj-and-solr-cell-apache-tika](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/09/14/posting-rich-documents-to-apache-solr-using-solrj-and-solr-cell-apache-tika/)
[indexing-rich-files-into-solr-quickly-and-easily](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2011/08/31/indexing-rich-files-into-solr-quickly-and-easily/)

Comment: how do i index the files though? do I just do "java -jar post.jar mydoc.doc"? Because I keep getting "FATAL: Solr returned an error #400 Bad Request" from that.

Comment: you can use curl commands to upload the files. Check for example @ http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Sending_documents_to_Solr